# C++ for loop diamond only negative numbers

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print a diamond the size of an amount passed as a parameter in the calling routine and if that number is even changed it to the next highest odd number starting at zero.
The function has default parameters if no amount or character type is passed. I can print a diamond that outputs symbols in lines of only  odd amounts, but I want it to print the odd lines of symbols passed up to a maximum line count of what was passed. My problem is that it prints an amount of lines equal to the number passed, giving each line only an odd amount of symbols instead of only the lines with an odd amount up to the amount passed. i.e. I pass it a 5 and it will print five separate lines starting with one symbol, then three symbols, then five symbols, then seven symbols, then nine symbols. I can't seem to make my brain understand how to differentiate between the line amount and the symbol amount. Any help is welcome and it's for a homework assignment so just need the logic behind what i'm doing wrong so I can figure it out. Thank you. Here's my code as of now. Using Eclipse as a compiler if that's of significance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// prototype for printDiamond
void printDiamond ( int = 1, char = '*' );

int main()
{
   printDiamond();
   cout << endl;
   printDiamond(1);
   cout << endl;
   printDiamond(2);
   cout << endl;
   printDiamond(3);
   cout << endl;
   printDiamond(4);
   cout << endl;
   printDiamond(5);
   cout << endl;
   printDiamond(1, '$');
   cout << endl;
   printDiamond(2, '$');
   cout << endl;
   printDiamond(3, '$');
   cout << endl;
   printDiamond(4, '$');
   cout << endl;
   printDiamond(5, '$');
   cout << endl;

   int someSize = 10;
   char someSymbol = ' ';
   printDiamond(someSize, someSymbol);
   cout << endl;

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void printDiamond ( int max, char symbol)
{

   if ( symbol == ' ')
      symbol = '*';
   if ( max % 2 == 0 )
            ++max;

   int shape,line;

   if ( max >= 0 )
   {

      if ( max % 2 )
      {

         for (shape=1;shape <= max ;shape++)
         {

            for (line = shape; line < max; line++)
            {
               cout << " " ;
            }

            for (line=1; line <= shape+shape-1; line++)
            {
               cout << symbol ;
            }
            cout << endl;

         }
      }
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "Input error. This function not defined for a negative integer.";
   }

   if ( max % 2 )
   {

      for (shape=max-1;shape >= 0 ;shape--)
      {

         for (line=shape;line<max;line++)
         {
            cout << " " ;
         }

         for (line=1;line <= shape+shape-1; line++)
         {
            cout << symbol ;
         }

         cout << endl;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm impressed you know what a loop is yet you decided against using it in your main function.

Comment: eclipse is the ide, not a compiler

Comment: Stackoverflow is intended as a repository of *knowledge* in the form of common questions and answers.  It is not intended as a general help forum.  See [about stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  Maybe there is a particular aspect of programming this task you need help with?

Comment: @Rapptz The exercise is in functions with default parameters so the point is to have a function do the work, not just output a diamond.

Comment: @artless noise My question was concerning logic and for loops. I gave my situation as a reference to what my code would do and how i understood the logic behind it.

Comment: @Beta Thanks for the quick response. I started over as suggested and tried to do it in a simpler fashion. I figured out where my thinking was wrong. Also changed my variables to better represent what I am trying to do.

Comment: @artlessnoise "This site is all about getting answers." AND "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced." taken directly from your link that I've already read. Seems to me that my question was fitting, your understanding was lacking.

Comment: Your question is unlikely to help anyone else in the world but yourself; or someone else in your class doing the assignment.  Your question is *conceptual*;  Ie, How do I do this.  There are about `inf` answers.  It is not a good question.

Comment: @artlessnoise At the very least my question dealt with how to interpret what the code I had typed meant i.e. syntax of C++ which can plainly translate to someone else seeing how typing something one way would lead to a certain answer whether they meant it that way or needed to rethink how they would retype their code based on their actual logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some of your logic looks wrong. You use `if ( max % 2 )` when it is certain to evaluate as `true`.

Second, your variables have bad names. It is not at all clear what `line` and `shape` are supposed to represent (certainly not a line and a shape, respectively).

Third, you're trying to do too much at once. Try something simpler. For an argument of 5, instead of trying to produce this:

```
  *
 ***
*****
 ***
  *
```

Try something simpler first, like this:

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

Or this:

```
*
***
*****
```

Or this:

```
1
3
5
```

Also, get used to thinking of even and odd numbers as `2n` and `2n+1`. That should be enough to get you over the hump.